# Visual Studio 2017 v15.3.0 - Modo depuração com bug

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Segue imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue código da imagem acima:

```
List<string> teste = new List<string>(new string[] { "0", "1", "2", "3", "4" });
```

Instalei a versão mais nova hoje (15.3.0). Alguém que está com a versão 15.3.0, e pode me dizer como ela está. Porque aqui está em branco. Está assim em qualquer projeto. Isso é normal ?

Comment: Qual é a linguagem?

Comment: Linguagem C# Renato

Comment: Eu testei no meu Visual Studio 2017 não apareceu nada

Comment: @RenatoSilva, "não apareceu nada", quer dizer que está igual meu ? tipo branco.

Comment: Não apareceu nem esta caixa de texto

Comment: Eita, que bug feio que a Microsoft fez.

Comment: @RenatoSilva, você está usando a versão preview ?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63893/discussion-between-matheus-miranda-and-renato-silva).